# Creating a .NET Service to run Oracle Query

Tags: c#, php, oracle, wcf

I have several services written in PHP that I'm migrating to .NET. I've attempted to use WCF, and Web API to connect to my Oracle database and pull information from that database, is it possible to run a query right from a web application or what is the proper way to do this? Here is the query that I'm trying to run:

```
select t2.meternumber, t1.blinkdate, t1.blinkcount
            from
              (select * from cecc_processed_blinks where trunc(blinkdate) between to_date(?, 'dd-mon-yy') and to_date(?, 'dd-mon-yy')) t1 
              left join meteraccts t2 on t1.serialnumber = t2.serialnumber
            where t2.meternumber = ?
            order by t1.blinkdate desc
```

I'm connected to my Oracle database at this point but I can't find much documentation on implementation of Oracle into .NET or at least that I understand being an inexperienced C# developer.

Comment: Have you tried looking for documentation on the web? There is a wealth of information available on this topic: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Oracle Managed ODP.NET [adapter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html).

The latest version has EF6 support, which should give you exactly what you need.

You can install it directly from the nuget command line with the following command:

```
Install-Package odp.net.managed
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using visual studio, open the Nuget Package Manager console and type this this:

```
Install-Package odp.net.managed
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/

After this its very easy. Add the using statements:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; // ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
```

Then make a query.....

```
string oradb = "Data Source=ORCL;User Id=hr;Password=hr;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
conn.Open(); 

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from some table";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 

OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
string text = dr.GetString(0);
conn.Dispose();
```

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm